# Every time I boot up my iMac "... is an app downloaded from Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?"

Tags: macos, imac

I get this popup every time I boot up my mac.

[image]

It's some adobe after effects script. I uninstalled after effects.

I typed in com.aescripts.ZXP-Installer.helper in finder and deleted anything that matched.

I've done a terminal `find / -name com.aescripts.ZXP-Installer.helper` with no luck.

Don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First place I'd check is System Preferences:

Users & Groups - Login Items.

Scroll through the list of items there, these will open upon log in (which may be part of your boot process), and delete `com.aescripts.ZXP-Installer.helper` if it is there.

If not there, try looking in the the following directories:

```
/Library/StartupItems
/System/Library/StartupItems
```

Comment: Only have a single item which is "Magnet" the windowing utility.

Comment: @coltonidle I just edited the answer - take a look in the two directories - maybe it is there?

Comment: Nothing in those directories. Funny enough... I just hit open and nothing ever popped up after it, and when I restart, I don't see it. Weird. Thanks for the help @Scot, will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

That `find` command is looking for an exact match of that name.  It's much better to go for a partial match, and use the various features of `grep` such as ignoring case (`grep -i`).  Further, that `find` operations is very, very slow.  So it's better to do it **once** and then use other tools to filter out the names you want.

Log in as an admin user.   Go to Terminal.   Go

```
  cd
  sudo find / > filelist
```

That creates a file in your home directory called 'filelist'.  This will be quite time-consuming, *but you only have to do it once*.    The reason to use 'sudo' is so you can see all directories, even those your user doesn't have permission to eXplore. Note that this will expose any other user's personal filenames on this Mac.

Now, still in terminal, and still in home directory, go

```
 cat filelist | grep (various query terms here, any you find useful).
```

This goes quite fast, so you are free to iterate on any term you think helpful.  (cat|grep so the grep phrase is at the very end of the command, so you can just hit up-arrow-backspace to change it).  I recommend starting with `ZXP-Installer` so...

```
 cat filelist | grep ZXP-Installer
```

This will give you a list of files and directories where *part of the name* includes that string. Given the uniqueness, I think you will only find files associated with it.